# Slide down menu bar using CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML5 and CSS3 menu bar that i've been working on and i'm trying to make it visible when hovering over a div. Any help on what i have done wrong will be much appreciated.

Here is my code, thankyou in advance:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Navigation
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Navigation.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubMenu 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="hideshow">
            <center>
                <p style="font-size: 25px">
                    .&nbsp.&nbsp.
                </p>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul ul 
{
    display: none;
}

nav
{
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul 
{
    display: block;
}

nav ul 
{
    margin-right: 1em;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #C6E2FF; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li 
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #ff5050;
    border-right: 20px solid #ff0000;
    border-left: 20px solid #ff0000;
}

nav ul li:hover 
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffa000;
    border-right: 40px solid #ff0000;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

nav ul li:hover a
{
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a 
{
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #e0e0e0; text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul 
{
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #C6E2FF; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li 
{
    float: none; 
    border-top: 3px solid #C6E2FF;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #C6E2FF;
    position: relative;     
}

nav ul ul li a 
{
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover 
{
    background: #ff5050;
    border-left: 12px solid #ffa000;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul ul li
{
    background: #ff5050;
    border-left: 12px solid #ffa000;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

nav ul ul li:hover
{
    background: #ff5050;
    border-left: 12px solid #ffa000;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    background-color: #ff5050;
}

nav ul:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}

#hideshow
{
    border: 2px dashed #e0e0ee;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#hideshow:hover  nav  ul
{
    display: inline-table;
    border: 2px dashed #e0e0ee;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

#hideshow  p
{
    color: #9C9C78;
}
```

Comment: its work perfect whats wrong ?

Comment: That's strange because i'm using Google Chrome and it's not working

Comment: i m also use chrome. say me hover effect not work

Comment: Hmm... maybe just need to update my chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could that by using the "adjacent sibling combinator"

```
#hideshow:hover + nav {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is an jsfiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw4fe/)

But this way you won't be able to use it. If you want to use it you have to restructure your markup. For Example by putting the nav element into the div element.
Here is another jsfiddle: [Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw4fe/1/)